# Can you make Mutant League Football enforce the deaths seen at half time?

Tags: mutant-league-football

In the game Mutant League Football if you watch the other games that occur at halftime you can often see players on the field being killed.  However, when you play these teams later on in the playoffs (even the next game) none of their players seem to be missing.  My question is how does one enforce the players on the computer controlled teams to be dead when witnessing them die at the halftime of other games?

Comment: They come back to life.  MUTANTS.  Your team is, uh, just special.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid that isn't possible.  Whenever you play a team in the playoffs, they start off with a full roster, even if your roster is severely depleted by prior games.

It's part of what makes winning the championship with a high Death Index so difficult, as you have to conserve your players, in addition to winning the games.

I should also note that regardless of how high a Death Index you play the championship on, the highlights are always shown as if you had selected the highest index, resulting in the maximum amount of carnage during the highlight.

Comment: Pity, I still wish they would remake this.

Comment: JOCKSTRAP SNAPPED BY SPEW PUKE 1 YD LOSS - Classic...

Comment: WinkyStink park which was where the sixty whiners played I think.  In hindsight completely inappropriate